# Error when adding a custom lightning component with Lightning App Builder

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have created a Lightning component with following codes

Component Code

```
<aura:component controller="stDocus" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:editRecord" type="EVENT" />
    <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT" />
    <aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="string" />
    <aura:attribute name="docObj" type="List" />

    <div style="margin:30px auto; text-align:center; width:100%">
        <aura:iteration var="sld" items="{!v.docObj}">
            <div style="float:left; width:18%; margin:1%;">
                <img width="100%" id="theImage1" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/512/PowerPoint_alt.png"/>
                <a href="{! '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+sld.Id}" target="_blank" id="theLink1">{!sld.Name}</a>
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller code

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getdocs");
        action.setParams({
            recordId: recordId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var doc = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.docObj", doc);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller code

```
public  class stDocus
 {
    @AuraEnabled
    //public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
    public Opportunity Oppo{get;set;}

 public List<Document> getdocs(String recordId)
 {
        Oppo = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :recordId];
        List<Document> doc = [SELECT Id, Name, FolderId, Folder.Name FROM Document WHERE Folder.Name like :Oppo.StageName];
        return doc;
 }
}
```

When I drag the custom Lightning component from the left side to the desired section of the Opportunity Record Page using Lightning App Builder, I get the following error as popup.

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. Unable to parse JSON
>   response

I didn't get any error code. But when I inspected the console, I got the following log messages

> Error in Surface: Unable to parse JSON response
>   components/flexipageEditor/surface.js:5 Error in Surface: This page
>   has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed:
>   flexipageEditor:component$controller$generate [$A.util.aa.ib(...) is
>   not a function] Failing descriptor:
>   {flexipageEditor:component$controller$generate}

Could you please help me find the issue and fix it?? I am stuck..

---

I have modified my code as per @Itai Shmida's suggestions in the comments. Now I am getting new errors.

> Assertion Failed!: Unknown controller action 'getdocs' : undefined
>   pC.log()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:192:319
>   pC.assert()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:189:393
>   $.A.assert()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:682:279
>   iD.get()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:299:377
>   b.L.get()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:265:423
>   doInit()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:147:402
>   H.Gc()@https://vofox-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/YfjoKfTjN2bVGUBUXXcoWw/aura_prod.js:332:170

Please help.

Comment: I would start by checking if `recordId` is empty in your doinit and if it is then exit. When you add to the layout in the app builder it runs the component to give you a preview. Since there will be no record Id your query in the class will throw an error and possibly an internal error. So give that a try and see if it helps. Or in your class check if null and return null.

Comment: You should add to your markup: `<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />`. also - I cannot see an attribute named `docObj` in your markup - according to your controller, you should add it also.

Comment: @ItaiShmida: I have added those attributes (updated the code in question. Please see). Still the same error.

Comment: In your sever side function you are returning a list of documents and in your client side - the attribute is one document

Comment: Oh. Ok. How can I make the attribute a list of documents? I am new to salesforce development. :(

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm

Comment: @ItaiShmida I am getting new error when I changed the code. I have updated it in my question. Please see and advise if you know what is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the

```
@AuraEnabled
```

annotation to the method in your controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Document> getdocs(String recordId)
 {
        Oppo = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :recordId];
        List<Document> doc = [SELECT Id, Name, FolderId, Folder.Name FROM Document WHERE Folder.Name like :Oppo.StageName];
        return doc;
 }
```

Comment: When I did that, I am getting another error - "Non static AuraEnabled methods may not have parameters"

Comment: Fixed it @AeJey